# How to write an abbreviated version of the if record for this code?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

How to write an abbreviated version of the if record for this code?
Rewrite the same script making it one-liner. (if else)

Linux RedHat 4-5

```
!/bin/bash
for file in /etc/*; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]
    then
        echo "$file is a regular file"
    elif [ -d "$file" ]
    then
        echo "$file is a directory"
    else
        echo "$file is something else"
    fi
done
```

Rewrite the same script making it one-liner. (if else)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is better, but this will work:

```
([ -f "$file" ] && echo "regular") || ( [ -d "$file" ] && echo "dir" ) || echo "wtf"
```